# Show push notifications once for a website

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, push

Hello I'm a new developer and I'm looking to add push notifications to my website but I only want them to be shown one time to the user. Or should I use a different type of notification.

Here is my code in javascript:

```
Notification.requestPermission(); 

var data = { 
     name: "Malvern Prime News Notification ",
     newEp: "A New Episode is now available ", 
     newJob: "A New Job offer is now open ", 
     webLocation: "https://www.malvernprimenews.cf" 
}

var e = new Notification(data.name, {
}); 

e.onclick = function() {
    location.href = data.webLocation
}
```

Comment: Tell us more about the use case of the notification

Comment: Hey I want to use notifications to tell the user when a new advent has happened on the website and ideally it only shows it to them once and that’s when I re-upload the website